# Resizing console size programmable in C

Tags: c, console

I have two arrays 9x9 that are displayed one below another but the problem is that the console is too small. Is there a way to resize the console height through code? It is a windows program, battle ships of some sort.

Comment: Please edit your question with correct spelling and further information.

Comment: @Wooble can you explain to me why this would be true? There is generally a base video driver but if vesa is available wouldn't console size be limited to that?

Answer (score 1):

Use a shortcut that contains this command for windows:

`cmd.exe /k "MODE CON: COLS=80 LINES=32"`

Comment: @user1601731 You would open the console program this way. You would probably want to open your game along with it, so in your shortcut add the full path to your executable after cmd.exe,

And you would create a desktop shortcut this way. This is only one way to do it that is fairly quick.